# When transform: scale(1); align image to the side and sometimes to top and bottom

Tags: html, css

In the hero in following page, first big image after 10 sec fill all the height, but not the full image will be visible

http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/

but in my solution, which was copied from Codrop also, all image will be visible, but height is smaller, and a black stripe will appear under the image.

Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0qXW.jpg)

```css
@keyframes ken-burn-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.ken-burn-in > img {
    animation: ken-burn-in 13s;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.ken-burn-center > img {
    animation: ken-burn-in 10s;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.ken-burn-out > img {
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1.1) !important;
    transition: transform 10s;
}
```

```js
import Navbar from 'tikexModule/components/Navbar'
import Footer from './Footer'

interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode
    isNavbarTransparent?: Boolean
}
const Layout = ({ children, isNavbarTransparent }: Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror ken-burn-center"
                data-source-id="section_RIZ3d"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '450px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror"
                data-source-id="section_oxy7k"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '595px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-2.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror ken-burn-center"
                data-source-id="section_5ZtkF"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'visible',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '-70px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '972px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: '-131px',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div id="preloader" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
            <nav
                id="nav"
                className="scroll-change menu-classic  menu-fixed menu-transparent  light align-right  menu-one-page"
                data-menu-anima="fade-in"
                data-scroll-detect="true"
            >
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="menu-brand">
                        <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music">
                            <img
                                className="logo-default"
                                src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/08/logo-light.svg"
                                alt=""
                                style={{}}
                            />
                            <img
                                className="logo-retina"
                                src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/08/logo-light.svg"
                                alt=""
                                style={{}}
                            />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <i className="menu-btn" />
                    <div className="menu-cnt">
                        <ul id="main-menu">
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#features">Features</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#news">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="   dropdown ">
                                <a href="#">Pages</a>
                                <ul
                                    className="dropdown-menu fade-in"
                                    style={{
                                        animationDuration: '250ms',
                                        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                        transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Sites</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/saas/">
                                                    Saas
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/fintech/">
                                                    Fintech
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/chat/">
                                                    Chat
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/sport/">
                                                    Sport
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/food/">
                                                    Food
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/">
                                                    Music
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/photo/">
                                                    Photo
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/travel/">
                                                    Travel
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/news/">
                                                    News
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/">
                                                    Intro
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Pages</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/about-us/">
                                                    About
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/careers/">
                                                    Careers
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/faq/">
                                                    Faq
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/stories/">
                                                    Success stories
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/pricing-one/">
                                                    Pricing one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/pricing-two/">
                                                    Pricing two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/team/">
                                                    Team
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/shop/">
                                                    Shop
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/blog-one/">
                                                    Blog one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/blog-two/">
                                                    Blog two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/blog/2019/09/03/who-was-the-man-wearing-the-1-3-million-watch-stolen-in-spain/">
                                                    Post
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-one/">
                                                    Contacts one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-two/">
                                                    Contacts two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-three/">
                                                    Contacts three
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className=" ">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            href="https://templates.themekit.dev/codrop/elements/components/buttons.html"
                                        >
                                            Elements
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="menu-right">
                            <div className="menu-custom-area">
                                <a className="btn btn-xs btn-border btn-circle" href="#">
                                    Download App
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <main className="footer-parallax-cnt" style={{ marginBottom: '442px' }}>
                <section
                    id="section_5ZtkF"
                    className="section-image hc-cmp-section  light  section-bottom-layer  ken-burn-center"
                    data-parallax="scroll"
                    data-natural-height={1080}
                    data-natural-width={1920}
                    data-position
                    data-image-src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                >
                    <div className="container ">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div
                                id="column_3LmOZ"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <hr id="C2Ryb" className="hc-cmp-space space    " />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_OfRKu"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6   fade-in"
                                style={{
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                    transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                    transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                }}
                                data-anima
                                data-time={1000}
                                aid="0.5738936811843882"
                            >
                                <hr
                                    id="DPLpC"
                                    className="hc-cmp-space space-lg  hidden-md   "
                                />
                                <h1 id="BdEnF" className="hc-cmp-title-tag    " style={{}}>
                                    The funny app, to share and listen your music
                                    <span className="dot">.</span>
                                </h1>
                                <p id="9EIqX" className="hc-cmp-text-block    " style={{}}>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                                    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                                    laboriso.
                                </p>
                                <hr id="RFBds" className="hc-cmp-space space-sm    " />
                                <div id="57Igh" className="hc-cmp-code-block    ">
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        className="btn btn-sm text-bold btn-circle shadow-1 full-width-sm"
                                    >
                                        Download now
                                    </a>
                                    <span className="space-sm" />
                                    <a href="#" className="btn-text active hidden-sm">
                                        Discover the music
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <hr id="pWrRN" className="hc-cmp-space space-xs    " />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_I8mak"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6   fade-bottom"
                                style={{
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                    transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                    transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                }}
                                data-anima
                                data-time={1000}
                                aid="0.8009226736862343"
                            >
                                <hr id="Q0JeD" className="hc-cmp-space space  visible-md   " />
                                <div id="cparo" className="hc-cmp-code-block    ">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
             
            </main>

        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;` property on the image?

Comment: Yes, does not help. I would bet some logic is not triggered in the main.js file: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/plugins/hybrid-composer/scripts/main.js The only difference is, there is an extra <div> between body and the top elements.

Comment: I have checked the framework link you have attached and it looks like it has achieved it by using padding bottom on the div container holding those texts and main heading, download now and discover elements. Also for the black strip, there is `:after` pseudo element on the same div container with height of 100px with white background which makes it look the way it does. You can check it in the dev tools and see if it is the case.